# Importing library in a method rather than in constructor

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, angular-universal

I am working with Angular Universal and some 3rd party libs are causing issues with window not defined, i tried many approaches but this works by delaying the import until we know its a browser, but my question is, is this a bad practice, what are the potential downsides of this ?

```
if( isPlatformBrowser(self._platformId) ){ import( 'zuck.js' ).then( res =>{ Zuck = res; }
```